# Checking free space available in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am confused. here the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.availablefreespace(v=vs.96).aspx

say, I need 3 mb space and using below code:

is this store.AvailableFreeSpace:

1) checking The entire storage for the Phone or Total storage space in the master isolatedstorage?

2) or checking the space for my App?

Thanks

```
private bool IsSpaceIsAvailable(long spaceReq)        
{            
using (IsolatedStorageFile store =IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())    
{               
 long spaceAvail = store.AvailableFreeSpace;               
 if (spaceReq > spaceAvail)               
 {                   
 return false;                
}                
return true;            
}        
}
```

Comment: I think i got it. Quota refer to the entire storage space. This method return the total space available. If there is no space, i can start to delete file in Pic Hub or not important files. thanks

Comment: Well, isolated storage works on  per-application basis in WP7. So every call you do and information you get is related only to your app

Answer (score 0):

There is no quota on Silverlight for Windows Phone. Single app is allowed to take entire drive. API calls referring to quota either assume your app quota is MAXLONG or throw an exception.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28VS.95%29.aspx#IsolatedStorage